# Terminating all Child Processes in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I made an application in Qt, in which I use QProcess to start a process as root, after showing a dialog to enter the root password. The new process runs as root. If I terminate the application using a button, the child process doesnt terminate. How do I ensure that the child process also terminates when the main application terminates?

Comment: do you handle Qt signals from your QProcess ? Show the code please!